# How to display two select statements from two different tables into a single table with columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a table t1 and I want to find out the sum of the few columns by year,month.

```
SELECT 
         SUM(SA) as SA,
        SUM(TM) as TM,
        SUM(ST) as ST       
    FROM t1
GROUP BY YEAR(createdDate), MONTH(createdDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(createdDate), MONTH(createdDate)
```

The second table  t2 is

```
SELECT 
         SUM(BA) as BA,
        SUM(TR) as TR   
    FROM t2
GROUP BY YEAR(createdDate), MONTH(createdDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(createdDate), MONTH(createdDate)
```

the  output for respective tables is

**Table 1**

```
76.45   416.51  2484.89
80.28   296.18  1909.83
78.57   342.27  4798.71
```

**Table 2**

```
1924.9  0
1689.85 0
4608.69 0
```

But I want to represent as a single table as

```
76.45   416.51  2484.89    1924.9   0
80.28   296.18  1909.83    1689.85  0
78.57   342.27  4798.71     4608.69 0
```

I don't have common column to join.So I have to do without join

Comment: What happened to the Year and Month columns? did you just leave it out from the sample  -OR- why `group by YEAR(createdDate), MONTH(createdDate)` if the columns aren't important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe your examples are complete, and you probably do not need a `FULL OUTER JOIN` but until more is known that will suffice. The point is you have both year and month as potential column in common

```
SELECT
      coalesce(a.yr,b.yr) yr
    , coalesce(a.mn, b.mn) mn
    , a.SA, a.TM, a.ST, b.BA, b.TR
FROM (
      SELECT
            YEAR(createdDate) yr
          , MONTH(createdDate) mn
          , SUM(SA) AS SA
          , SUM(TM) AS TM
          , SUM(ST) AS ST
      FROM t1
      GROUP BY
            YEAR(createdDate)
          , MONTH(createdDate)
      ) a
      FULL OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT
                  YEAR(createdDate) yr
                , MONTH(createdDate) mn
                , SUM(BA) AS BA
                , SUM(TR) AS TR
            FROM t2
            GROUP BY
                  YEAR(createdDate)
                , MONTH(createdDate)
      ) b ON a.yr = b.yr
                  AND a.mn = b.mn
```

Another possibility is that you are filtering for specific date ranges (say 2014, 2015 and 2016) and you know there is data in both tables for all those years and months, so you an use an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT
      a.yr, a.mn
    , a.SA, a.TM, a.ST, b.BA, b.TR
FROM (
      SELECT
            YEAR(createdDate) yr
          , MONTH(createdDate) mn
          , SUM(SA) AS SA
          , SUM(TM) AS TM
          , SUM(ST) AS ST
      FROM t1
      where somedatecolumn >= '20140101' and somedatecolumn < '20170101'
      GROUP BY
            YEAR(createdDate)
          , MONTH(createdDate)
      ) a
      INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                  YEAR(createdDate) yr
                , MONTH(createdDate) mn
                , SUM(BA) AS BA
                , SUM(TR) AS TR
            FROM t2
            where somedatecolumn >= '20140101' and somedatecolumn < '20170101'
            GROUP BY
                  YEAR(createdDate)
                , MONTH(createdDate)
      ) b ON a.yr = b.yr
                  AND a.mn = b.mn
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT  YEAR(createdDate) cYear, MONTH(createdDate) cDate,
     SUM(SA) as SA,
    SUM(TM) as TM,
    SUM(ST) as ST,
    T.BA,T.TR       
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN  (SELECT YEAR(createdDate) cYear, MONTH(createdDate) cDate,
     SUM(BA) as BA,
    SUM(TR) as TR   
FROM t2 GROUP BY YEAR(createdDate), MONTH(createdDate) )T ON .cYear=YEAR(t1.createdDate) AND T.cDate=MONTH(t1.createdDate) GROUP BY YEAR(t1.createdDate), MONTH(t1.createdDate),T.BA,T.TR ORDER BY YEAR(t1.createdDate), MONTH(t1.createdDate)
```

Comment: a Cartesian product of the tables? (t1 rows multplied by t2 rows) - you would not get the same SUM() results